# Trying to solve error messages for a Pinescript indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, moving-average

I keep getting error messages writing the code for an indicator. I would like it to print a triangle when four conditions become true.

```
Condition 1 = 20ema crossunder 100ema 3 bars ago
Condition 2 = 20ema at 3 bars ago minus 20ema at current bar >= 29.4
Condition 3 = 100ema at 3 bars ago minus 100ema at current bar >=13.64
Condition 4 = 20ema at 33 bars ago minus 20ema at 3 bars ago >= 29.3`
```

This is my script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

EMA20_= ta.ema(close,20)
EMA100_= ta.ema(close,100)
bool isCond1 = (ta.crossunder(EMA20_, EMA100_)[3] and sum(EMA20_[3] - EMA20_[0])>= 29.4 and sum(EMA100_[3] - EMA100_[0])>= 13.6 and sum(EMA20_[33] - EMA20_[3])>= 29.3)

plot(ta.ema(close,20),color=color.red)
plot(ta.ema(close,100),color=color.blue)
plotshape(series = isCond1 , signal, "signal", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny, offset = - 2)
```

Comment: your code has other problems

Comment: Are you using chatGPT? Due to such poor accuracy Stackoverflow has [banned ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). TradingView has also decided [not to provide support](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/) for ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

To print a triangle when four conditions become true, try this:

```
plotshape(isCond1, "signal", shape.triangleup, location.top, size = size.tiny, offset = - 2)
```